# lapply with ggplot2, overlay histogram with colored geom_point and name plots according to lapply variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply

There are two parts to my question:

i. I want to overlay `geom_histogram` with `geom_point` for different `aes` variables

My data is:

```
    df_test <- data.frame(structure(list(A= c(-0.80146, 0.190611, 0.028847, 
0.026058, -0.021505, 0.540703, 0.052167, 0.203469, 0.069915, 
0.148333, 0.005477, -0.001109, -0.116027, 0.473616, 0.120469, 
0.11245, 0.100045, 1.781763, -0.177578, 0.134783, -0.099096, 
-0.077076, 0.193608, 0.407867, -0.039539, 0.13453, 1.173945, 
-0.797383, -0.277112, -0.164893, -0.265595, 0.003697, 0.998122, 
-0.080394, 0.085291, -0.805778, -0.071481, -0.344804, -0.353637, 
-0.198817, 0.77241, 0.169778, 0.063251, 0.024213), B= c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, -1L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, -1L, 0L, 0L), C= c("GM1", 
"GM2", "GM3", "GM4", "GM5", "GM6", "GM7", "GM8", "GM9", "GM1", 
"GM2", "GM3", "GM4", "GM5", "GM6", "GM7", "GM8", "GM9", "GM1", 
"GM2", "GM3", "GM4", "GM5", "GM6", "GM7", "GM8", "GM9", "GM1", 
"GM2", "GM3", "GM4", "GM5", "GM6", "GM7", "GM8", "GM9", "GM1", 
"GM2", "GM3", "GM4", "GM5", "GM6", "GM7", "GM8")), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
44L)))
```

My code is as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
regions = c('GM1', 'GM2', 'GM3', 'GM4', 'GM5', 'GM6', 'GM7', 'GM8', 'GM9')
hist_plot <- function(df){
  p = ggplot(df, aes(x=A)) + geom_histogram(fill='white', color='black')
  p = p + geom_point(aes(A,B)) + ggtitle(names(regions))
  p
}

p = lapply(df_test, hist_plot)
```

Expected output plot is kind of like this (ignore red arrows at the top):

[image]

I am not being able to:

i. color the geom_point and add a legend for them according to the variable `B`

ii. Name each plot according to the region it comes from in lapply

Can someone please advise? I tried adding color specifically to geom_point but got an error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you don't need the function and `lapply`. Nor the vector `regions`. All you need is `facet_wrap` as below.
What is more, `lapply(df, FUN)` will apply `FUN` to each *column* of `df`. This is because dataframes are lists in tabular format.

Now the code.

```
p <- ggplot(df_test, aes(x = A)) + 
     geom_histogram(fill = 'white', color = 'black') +
     geom_point(aes(A, B, color = B)) + ggtitle(names(C)) + 
     facet_wrap( ~ C)
p
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! I am ideally looking to color the `geom_point` points by the variable `B` as well as want an individual plot per GM region with a legend indicating colors of `B`. I also want to maintain `lapply` as opposed to `facet_wrap` because I want to extract individual plots for comparison

Comment: @ManasiShah See if this is it.